# 2 Attributes reference the same thing, when they are supposed to have unique values

Tags: mysql, database

I am having a bit of trouble setting up my database for my project. I am doing insert statements into my tables to "populate the database."
However if you scroll down to the bottom of my create tables, you will see that both "Location_Address_Pickup" and "Location_Address_Drop" both reference "Address" in my location table. However I need these 2 attributes to have their own values, and I can't do that when they're both referencing the same thing.. Should I reference these to something else to achieve this? I don't understand how this is supposed to be possible..

[Picture of my ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY7An.png)

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
Phone VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Location (
Address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Latitude VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
Longitude VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Address));


CREATE TABLE Employee (
EmployeeID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID));


CREATE TABLE Truck (
LicensePlate CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
color VARCHAR(45) NULL,
capacity VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LicensePlate));

CREATE TABLE Shifts (
ShiftTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ShiftTime));

CREATE TABLE EmployeeShifts (
DesiredShift DATETIME NOT NULL,
EmployeeWorking INT NULL,
DateOfShift DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(DesiredShift, EmployeeWorking),
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeWorking) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (DesiredShift) REFERENCES Shifts(ShiftTime));

CREATE TABLE Reservation (
ReservNum INT NOT NULL,
ReserveDate DATE NULL,
PickupTime VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
NumOfPassengers INT NULL,
sheduledTime VARCHAR(45) NULL,
ActualPickupTime VARCHAR(45),
ActualTime VARCHAR(45),
SalaryEarned VARCHAR(10),
PricePaid VARCHAR(45),
HourlyRate DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
Customer_CustomerID INT,
Truck_LicensePlate char(20) NOT NULL,
Employee_EmployeeID_Driver INT,
Location_Address_Pickup VARCHAR(100),
Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger INT,
Location_Address_Drop VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (ReservNum),
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID),
FOREIGN KEY (Truck_LicensePlate) REFERENCES Truck (LicensePlate),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Driver) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Pickup) REFERENCES Location (Address),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Drop) REFERENCES Location (Address));
```

Comment: The 'Location' table does not appear to have a valid normalized key.

Comment: What do I do to fix that?

Comment: It depends on the business rules. Is an address a *value* or an *identity*? Consider this: what is the expected value of 'address'? Can a Location be updated or changed?

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand there is a **Location** table which will have all addresses, Latitudes and Longitudes. So this **Location** table is kind of a master location table which can hold location of both Pickup, Drop and may be location of Employee and other locations relevant to application.

To answer your question, the Pickup and Drop address are referenced to correct primay key. You need to add Location entries of Drop & Pickup in **Location** table. And then you can insert one of the address as Drop and other as Pickup in **Reservation** table

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. You say they reference the correct entity. But if I were to add those 2 new entities to the location table, how can I still insert one address as drop and the other as pickup when they are both still referencing "address"? Unless I change them to reference the new entities?